# java SQLException Analysis

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, sqlexception

```
       Connection con;
       PreparedStatement ps,p2;


       try
       {
           sqlquery = "...";
           ps=con.prepareStatement(sqlquery);
           ps.executeUpdate();

          // using ps2...some similar process.......
       }
       catch(SQLException sqlex)
       {
              System.out.print(sqlex.getMessage());
       }
```

I've got a doubt that whether is

`Is it possible to find out the cause of the specific error made out by a query or update such that i can handle the situation other than just displaying the error message at output console (as here) displaying the cause ?`

for eg: if **if ps preparedStatement makes a mistake because of duplicate entry or ps because of some foreign key issues etc..then i should be able to analyze the sql error specifically** `using SQLException object` **so that i can handle accordingly rather than just displaying error message in the output console**

The reason for which i need this is because i want to display the error made by a user working through GUI scenario (in case : here java swing) any error entries he made through an interactive manner by analyzing the SQLException instance....

`In short , how to classify errors using a single SQLException instance`

**Sorry if this question finds ambigous or stupid..!!!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need the methods `getSQLState` and `getErrorCode` of class `SQLException`.

Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html) for further information.

I hope this helps!

Comment: @Vincenzo....So is it right that if i get an SQLException for a dupicate key situation.....it's errorcode would always be the same for that type of that situation...so that check that i can note down the error code and always check it the error code when an SQL Exception occurs...is that so...??

Comment: Yes, it can differ from db to db but for a single db type they are standard, and I think states are mainly standard, but you can check yourself. But please, for personal experience, use them for logging, not for taking decisions.

Comment: @Thihara: corrected! This is the result of just having woken up... -.-

Comment: Keep in mind that codes returned by `getSQLState()` are standardized (to an extent), while codes returned by `getErrorCode()` are implementation specific. That means you'll usually want to use `SQLState` codes. [More info here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html)

Answer (score 2):

When an `SQLException` is thrown, you can capture error state, error code and specific message using relevant methods from `SQLException` instance.

1. [`getErrorCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode%28%29),
2. [`getSQLState()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getSQLState%28%29),
3. and a common `getMessage()` of any exception.

MySQL has documented various common errors and problems at
[Appendix C. Errors, Error Codes, and Common Problems](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-handling.html), which you need to use in your `java` code and handle accordingly.

As *Vincenzo Maggio* referred, [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11374550/767881), your can [Handle SQL Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html) based on the error states and codes.

Please note that these error states, codes may not be the same in different database implementions.
Various Oracle error codes, ORA prefixed, can be found [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_error_code_list.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to solve this problem would be to get the error code (e.g.: 1045) using getErrorCode() and based on some predefined mappings of codes to user-readable messages that you defined in advance (in a file or hard coded) to return an easily understandable message.

A general solution would be to parse the message returned by getMessage() but I don't thing there is a well defined grammar for the exceptions thrown by a DBMS so such a solution wouldn't be feasible/implementable.

Comment: @Razvan....So is it right that if i get an SQLException for a dupicate key situation.....it's errorcode would always be the same for that type of that situation...so that check that i can note down the error code and always check it the error code when an SQL Exception occurs...is that so...??

Comment: For a particular DBMS what you said it works. It's unlikely that the error codes will differ for different versions of the same DBMS.
But for different DBMSs you have no guarantee the error codes will be the same.
A solution would be to create your own abstract set of  error codes and then add mapping from error codes specific to various DBMSs to your abstract set.
And, in the mapping I was talking about in the actual answer you should use your abstract codes.